# Patterns for undo-redo state traversal with Relay-GraphQL mutations

Tags: immutable.js, graphql, relayjs

Attaining undo/redo functionality with Immutable and a Flux implementation is basically trivial. This is in part due to the value-passing made possible by Immutable and in part because of the in-browser/in-memory nature of using Flux.

Conceptualizing this in terms of Relay-GraphQL mutations, however, is not obvious. Are there any known patterns out there that simplify this?

Comment: Can you clarify the use-case? Is the motivation for having undo/redo to enable debugging, or to provide a user-facing ability to undo/redo mutations that have been committed on the server?

Comment: @JoeSavona use-case is basically undo-redo functionality. But I've gotten to know GraphQL/Relay more since posting this question and it seems like that sort of functionality might be beyond their scope. Would be interesting to keep this in mind in terms of anything that *is* in scope and would aid in this type of functionality.

Comment: @JoeSavona thanks for your work and time. These are great projects.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Relay can't (yet) do local state. So your option at the moment is to a) store "drafts" of changes in a Flux store or b) create a draft type that you continually create new versions of via a mutation. You could track the new draft ids in the client and "undo" by reverting the active draft id.

Comment: To add to this I recommend using the very small libraries [immutable-diff](https://www.npmjs.com/package/immutable-diff) and [immutable-patch](https://www.npmjs.com/package/immutable-diff) to store mutations in the frontend, and then you can send the consolidated list of patches to the backend to perform the actual mutations.

Comment: This actually isn't true anymore. Relay does handle local state: https://relay.dev/docs/en/local-state-management.